# Why does the NSFWJS library require the model to be loaded every time before evaluating the model

Tags: javascript, performance, tensorflow, machine-learning

From this library (https://github.com/infinitered/nsfwjs) it says you can call the following.

```
import * as nsfwjs from 'nsfwjs'

const img = document.getElementById('img')

// Load model from my S3.
// See the section hosting the model files on your site.
const model = await nsfwjs.load()

// Classify the image
const predictions = await model.classify(img)
console.log('Predictions: ', predictions)
```

I am doing the following. I want to scan multiple images. If I have it like the following, the model evaluates the same every time.

```
async function filter_page(data){
  console.log('Filtering page');
  var sandBox = document.createElement("div");
  sandBox.innerHTML = data;
  var boxes = sandBox.getElementsByClassName('_4p2o _87m1');
  tf.enableProdMode();
  var model = await nsfwjs.load();
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      console.log(`${i} \/ ${boxes.length}`);
      var img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      img.src = boxes[i].getElementsByClassName("_1glk _6phc img")[0].src;
      img.height = 74;
      img.width = 74;
      // Works if I load model in for loop instead of out of it
      var predictions = await model.classify(img);
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(predictions));
      boxes[i].appendChild(textNode);
      //console.log(textNode)

  }
  return sandBox.innerHTML;
}
```

Why does the "var model = await nsfwjs.load();" have to be inside the for loop?
If I load the model every time in the for loop it will load but it is fairly slow 15-20+ seconds. If I load the model out of the for loop it is fast but returns the same result every time. I feel like I should be able to load the model just one time and preform multiple evaluations against it.

Should I create a web worker to evaluate each image instead? What would be the fastest way to evaluate about 10 74x74px images in under one or two seconds? On the NSFWjs demo website a single image can be evaluated in 400ms. I figured if I have a web workers on a quad core I could do 12 images in 1200 ms. But I am not sure if it is even needed.

![The Problem]https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCW8X.jpg

Comment: did you got any info about this issue?

Comment: No, I ended up giving up. Are you having the same issue? The network scores didn't end up being that good.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, hope it can help you:

**1. classify function accepts ImageData type, we can convert blob to ImageData.**

```
let blobToImageData = (blob: File): Promise<ImageData> => {
  let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image(200, 200)
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = (err) => reject(err)
    img.src = blobUrl
  }).then((img: any) => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl)
    // Limit to 256x256px while preserving aspect ratio
    let [w, h] = [img.width, img.height]
    let aspectRatio = w / h
    // Say the file is 1920x1080
    // divide max(w,h) by 256 to get factor
    let factor = Math.max(w, h) / 256
    w = w / factor
    h = h / factor

    // REMINDER
    // 256x256 = 65536 pixels with 4 channels (RGBA) = 262144 data points for each image
    // Data is encoded as Uint8ClampedArray with BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = 1
    // So each images = 262144bytes
    // 1000 images = 260Mb
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = w
    canvas.height = h
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

    return ctx!.getImageData(0, 0, w, h) // some browsers synchronously decode image here
  })
}
```

**2. load ImageData**

```
const model = await nsfwjs.load()
const imgData = await blobToImageData(file)
const predictions = await model.classify(imgData)
console.log('Predictions: ', predictions)
```